# Python PLY multiple rules

Tags: python, ply

In ply how can we distinguish between which rule was used -

example :-  '''
            p : a b |
                c   |
                d
            '''
so suppose we need to write different code for different rules. Then is there any elegant way to do so. One way as given in the manual is to use combination of rules and tokens but that I find does not always click.

Answer (score 0):

Simply break the expression into multiple rules, with one rule for each different code.

e.g. (from http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn25)

```
def p_expression(p):
    '''expression : expression PLUS term
              | expression MINUS term'''
    if p[2] == '+':
        p[0] = p[1] + p[3]
    elif p[2] == '-':
        p[0] = p[1] - p[3]
```

can also be written as

```
def p_expression_plus(p):
    'expression : expression PLUS term'
    p[0] = p[1] + p[3]

def p_expression_minus(t):
    'expression : expression MINUS term'
    p[0] = p[1] - p[3]
```

Comment: Yes we can do that but imagine the blow up in the number of lines of code. We can also use different markers one for each row. I wanted to know if there is some variable such as rule which tells which rule was used. Anyway thanks.

Comment: Ah, I understand, sorry!  I am afraid I don't know of a variable to tell which rule was used.  (I guess you are expecting code blow up as you have very similar code for the different rules.  Perhaps you could call a helper function to parse similar rules and then the overhead of splitting into different functions would not be as costly?)

Comment: This won't work in case of a more complicated grammar where rules with different precedence need `%pred` to avoid reduce-reduce conflicts, as these rules need to be at the same level.

Answer (score -1):

To have multiple parser is not a problem, please check the PLY documenation (here
http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn37)

```
lexer  = lex.lex()       # Return lexer object
parser = yacc.yacc()     # Return parser object
```

Next, when parsing, make sure you give the parse() function a reference to the lexer it should be using. For example:

```
parser.parse(text,lexer=lexer)
```

If you forget to do this, the parser will use the last lexer created--which is not always what you want.

so, you can include some attributes

In the parser, the "lexer" and "parser" attributes refer to the lexer and parser objects respectively.

```
def p_expr_plus(p):
   'expr : expr PLUS expr'
   ...
   print p.parser          # Show parser object
   print p.lexer           # Show lexer object
```

More details can be found here

http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn37

Comment: He's not asking about multiple lexers and multiple parsers - the question is about multiple grammar rules in an individual parser.